# Finding Missing Elements among a range of number lines

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say I have a list of ranges (ie. `[[1,100][102, 200], etc]]`. I want to find the number of missing elements in the total range. I have a working algorithm below:

```
def missing(numranges):
    (minimum, maximum) = (min(map(lambda x: x[0], numranges)),
                          max(map(lambda x: x[1], numranges)))
    (count, i) = (0, minimum)

    while i < maximum:
        if any(j <= i <= k for j, k in numranges):
            count += 1
        i += 1

return maximum - minimum - count
```

The problem is if you have say a number line that say is like `[[1, 10000], [10002, 20000]]`, then i goes over all 20,000 elements and it seems to me that this is very inefficient. I'm trying to find a way to make the algorithm better but I'm a bit stumped.

Edit: Sorry, should have mentioned that the number ranges could overlap (ie. `[1, 10000], [1, 100001], [100003, 100005], etc]]`

Comment: If your code is working and you just want help improving it then I suggest you post it on [Codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Harrison. Sorry, will do so in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this code

```
l=[[1, 50], [55, 90], [95, 100]]
res=[]
for item in l :
    res.extend(range(item[0],item[1]))
print [k for k in range(max(res)) if k not in res]
```

Output :

```
[0, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I am assuming based on your example that your list is in increasing order and your ranges will not overlap

```
>>> l = [[1, 50] ,[55, 90], [95, 100]]
>>> sum([l[i+1][0]-m[1]-1 for i, m in enumerate(l[:-1])])
8
```

**Logic**: I am subtracting index 0 of the sublist with index 1 of the previous sublist. It is most optimised way to achieve what you want.

Comment: There are 8 numbers missing here, not 10: 51, 52, 53, 54, 91, 92, 93 and 94.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
In [22]: input_list = [range(1,100),range(102, 200)]
In [23]: total_list = sum(input_list,[])
In [24]: master_total_list = range(min(total_list),max(total_list)+1)
In [25]: [i for i in master_total_list if i not in total_list]
Out[25]: [100, 101]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sets to solve this:

```
test = set(range(1, 100 + 1) + range(102, 200 + 1))
missing = list(set(range(min(test), max(test))) - test)
print (missing)
```

Comment: Here you are creating a set of all the numbers and subtracting it with the ranges in the list and you call this as optimised? Seriously?

Comment: Seriously! This is code that's dead simple to understand, the optimization is that it takes seconds to write. Unless you want to check ranges of a million numbers this is so fast that it's not worth optimizing. But you got a point there are well... Just for fun I tried it with one million numbers. The result came in 100ms, right after I pressed Enter...